# Sending a command when the shortcut exists

Tags: autohotkey

I've got a global command like this

`!i::Send {Up}`  (pressing `alt+I` will move the caret up)

There is an application that uses `Alt+I` as a shortcut for an action that I'd like to call while still retaining my own custom shortcut. I'd like to remap this app's action to `Ctrl+I`

Within a proper WinExists, I've tried `^i::Send !{i}`  but that just moves the caret up.
I tried `^i::!i` but that sends `Ctrl+Alt+I` and not `Alt+I`.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gabe,

Try this...

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2 ; Accept the title search string to be found anywhere in title

#ifWinnotActive yourappname ; use windowspy to find a unique title string
!i::Send {Up}
#ifWinActive
```

This will set !i to behave just like you want in ALL programs except for the one you want to keep the special behaviour.

Alternatively, you could add a $ to the triggers, so they will not call each other like this:

```
$!i::Send, {Up}
$^i::Send, !i
```

Answer (score 1):

After each command, you need to add the command return. So if you have the code:

```
!i::Send, ^i
return
^i::Send, !i
return
```

The code above inverts the functions of <kbd>CTRL + i</kbd> and <kbd>ALT + i.</kbd>